# In place member initialization and aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, initialization

I have this simple struct and a function taking it:

```
struct S
{
    int a;
};

void foo(S){}

foo({5});
```

This works fine.

But if I change `int a;` to `int a{0};` VisualStudio (2013 and 2015) complains:

```
error C2664: 'void foo(S)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to 'S'
```

I can't find corresponding rule for this in the documentation. But both `gcc` and `clang` accept this without problem.

Comment: For visual, you may use `int a = 0;`

Comment: It's fine [here](http://rextester.com/LPDXHY82020).

Comment: @Jarod42 I have the same error.

Comment: @songyuanyao, I see it works, but here http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ (which is the same major version) it doesn't. Now I think the behavior depends on some compiler option.

Comment: @nikitablack: Your sample with any of `int a{0};` or `int a = 0;` works on  webcompiler.cloudapp.net for me...

Comment: @Jarod42, songyuanyao, I apologize but I didn't mentioned in the post that you should call `foo()` with aggregate initialization: `foo({5});`

Comment: For gcc/clang `foo({5});` compiles in c++14 but not in C++11. I think aggregate rule change from those 2 standards. (`S` is now an aggregate).

Comment: See [what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special-c++14](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27511360/2684539)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct S
{
    int a;
};
```

is an aggregate
whereas

```
struct S
{
    int a {0}; // or int a = 0;
};
```

is not an aggregate in c++11, but is in c++14.

VisualStudio (2013 and 2015) still uses the c++11 rules in this regard.

`foo({5});` is valid for aggregate. For non aggregate, it will (try to) call appropriate constructor, but `S` doesn't have one valid for this argument.