# Initializing a struct with aggregate initialization and member initializers

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, aggregate-initialization

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct ABC
{
    std::string str;
    unsigned int id ;/* = 0 : error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'ABC'*/
};

int main()
{
    ABC abc{"hi", 0};
    std::cout << abc.str << " " << abc.id <<   std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When defining the structure ABC without default value for id clang 3.x and gcc 4.8.x compile the code without problems. However, after adding a default argument for "id" I get the flowing error message:

```
13 : error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'ABC'
ABC abc{"hi", 0};
^ ~~~~~~~~~
4 : note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
struct ABC
^
4 : note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
4 : note: candidate constructor (the implicit default constructor) not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
1 error generated.
Compilation failed
```

From a technical point of view, what is going on when I define id with a default argument and why is aggregate initialization not possible in that case? Do I implicitly define some sort of constructor?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. Is [this](http://ideone.com/NMAmG4) what you wanted?

Comment: @erip That's interesting. It fails to compile in VS 2015.

Comment: Just found this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769246/in-place-member-initialization-and-aggregate-initialization) in regards to VS 2015. Looks like it might be the same issue for your compiler.

Comment: @erip This works fine with C++14 and seems not to work for C++11.

Comment: @user3472628: See my answer for the reason.

Comment: @Destructor Chapeau bas my friend.

Comment: uuplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118535/c11-aggregate-initialization-for-classes-with-non-static-member-initializers

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Bjarne Stroustrup and Richard Smith raised an issue about aggregate initialization and member-initializers not working together.

The definition of aggregate is slightly changed in C++11 & C++14 standard.

From the C++11 standard draft [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section 8.5.1 says that:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), ***no brace-or-equal- initializers for non-static
>   data members*** (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

But C++14 standard draft [n3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) section 8.5.1 says that:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

So, when you use in class member initializer (***i.e. equal initializer***) for the data member `id` in C++11 it no longer remains aggregate & you can't write `ABC abc{"hi", 0};` to initialize a `struct ABC.` Because it no longer remains aggregate type after that. But your code is valid in C++14. (See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/VeEfSO)).

Comment: Excellent comparison between standards. +1

Comment: For anyone who is interested in seeing a list of [C++11/14/17 features that Visual Studio 2015 supports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). Note that it does NOT support NSDMIs for aggregates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That really helped! +1

Answer (score -1):

In c++ struct and classes are the same, except that structs have default public members and classes have private. If you want to use initial values I think you have to write a constructor or use something like this:

```
struct ABC
{
    std::string str;
    unsigned int id;
} ABC_default = {"init", 0 }; //initial values

int main()
{
    ABC abc = ABC_default;
    std::cout << abc.str << " " << abc.id << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't really think this answers OP's question.

Comment: It's also wrong, since NSDMI were added to the language five years ago. The C-like syntax doesn't help the answer either. And not to sound like a broken record or anything but "struct and classes" aren't "the same"; `struct` introduces a _class_ and structs don't exist!

Comment: By saying that "struct and classes are the same" I mean that they are the same kind, only the keyword are different. Thanks for the reply

Comment: This is really inflexible. What is someone wants to initialize ABC multiple times? Will he have to constantly keep specifying a new type of ABC in the definition of ABC?